# ASP.NET c# 2.0 subfolder login

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

I am coming from Java and PHP world, so .net is a bit unknown to me. What i need to do is a simple one user login, and protect 2-3 pages in the same subfolder (ex. main site is at ./ and my new login should be just for these 2-3 files in ./home).

This is kind of simple admin, that in php i would have done it in less than 10 minutes :) and here is causing me all sorts of headaches. What i have ended now is i have made a simple Forms authentication, with the hardcoded username and pass, and i have protected the needed pages in web.config (all works great on my local server), but now when i uploaded it to the live server, with the web.config inside the ./home folder, i get an error that i haven't specified an application folder correctly in IIS (and i have no idea how to do this on live server, if i only have access on ftp). Then i tried updating the ./ web.config, so that points to login.aspx in ./home (using subfolders), that didn't work too because it wasn't protecting the pages it needed to protect.

Please help, and point me to right direction,

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to read about [ASP.NET form authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx). This will serve your purposes. Take a look at tutorial on [form authentication](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-vb).